# Azure AD OAuth token refresh gives error AADSTS50000

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, refresh-token

After successfully authenticating, I want to refresh my authorization token, so I issue the following request

```
curl -X POST \
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -F grant_type=refresh_token \
  -F refresh_token=<my-refresh-token> \
  -F client_id=<my-client-id> \
  -F client_secret=<my-client-secret>
```

However, instead of returning with a new token, I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": "server_error",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token.\r\nTrace ID: bb72ee21-7df2-4949-8375-e6d97b621300\r\nCorrelation ID: 719ea759-622b-4d63-be17-56fd6c255195\r\nTimestamp: 2018-06-15 09:07:13Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50000
    ],
    "timestamp": "2018-06-15 09:07:13Z",
    "trace_id": "bb72ee21-7df2-4949-8375-e6d97b621300",
    "correlation_id": "719ea759-622b-4d63-be17-56fd6c255195"
}
```

The tenant, client id and client secret are all the same as those used when obtaining the refresh token. Yet, something is apparently missing or incorrect - but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the mandatory `scope` parameter [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#refresh-the-access-token).

You also need to provide a `redirect_uri`, although you just make a POST request.

And the `redirect_uri` must match the `redirect_uri` used in the original authorization call.

When refreshing an access token you have to provide a scope for which you would like to get the token. Also make sure that you understand you can only refresh the access_token, not the id_token. And access_token always has a purpose (scope).

Everything described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! In addition to requiring that the `redirect_uri` matches the one the original token used, it also turned out to require matching the scopes exactly. With that in place, it worked :)

Comment: Yeah, also described - the same or a subset of original scopes. I am glad that it works now ;)