# AAD acquireToken fails with Android MSAL 2.0+ when using ForceLogin for UiBehavior

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

1. When using an application scope (api: //xxxxxxxx-b1df-4a7c-aaf9-44acc9b00fc9/access_as_user), we are able to get a token if we use the default uiBehavior (prompt)
2. When we switch the uiBehavior to ForceLogin, we fail with the listed error.
3. Note: This works in MSAL in Windows.
4. Note: On Android, ForceLogin works when we specify the scope “https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read”

The error received is:

> Authentication failed: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalServiceException: server_error;AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token.

The details are:
We create the publicClientApplication using the following Authority
Authority : https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-de11-4a26-95f4-ce61675ed639/v2.0/
Where xxxxxxxx-de11-4a26-95f4-ce61675ed639 is our tenant ID.

We then call
publicClientApplication.acquireToken(activity, SCOPES, email, uiBehavior, null, getAuthInteractiveCallback(activity)); -

Below are the parameters used:

email: “zzz@zzzzzz.ws” where zzz@zzzzzz.ws is a legitimate email address in our tenant
uiBehavior: ForceLogin
Scopes: {“api: //xxxxxxxx -b1df-4a7c-aaf9-44acc9b00fc9/access_as_user”}

Comment: In addition to specifying the scope, you need to ensure that your redirect_uri/reply urls are matching. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872434/azure-ad-oauth-token-refresh-gives-error-aadsts50000)

At what stage do you see this error? Can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: We verified by passing the redirect_uri configured in the azure account but this didn't work and same exception '**MsalServiceException: server_error;AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token**' is caught. We are facing this issue during the authentication stage after entering the password and clicking on Sign In button  in MSAL auth page.